# How to translate "Argument To Proof of Work"

Tags: idiom, latin-to-english-translation

Is the following the correct way to translate Argument To Proof of Work

```
Argumentum Ad Probationem Operis
```

The intention is to translate it in the same way as Argument to the Person

```
Argumentum Ad Hominem
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain a bit what you mean by "argument to proof of work"? An example situation might help find a good translation.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks! I'm trying to coin a phrase I suppose. There are a common list of fallacies which start with Argumentum.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies

Argument from authority would probably be the closest to what I'm talking about. `argumentum ad verecundiam`

So I'm trying to say something similar, but saying the argument is made from proof of work rather than authority (which is a form of authority in Bitcoin). Proof of work is a Bitcoin term used to describe how more bitcoins are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic structure you want is *argumentum ad…* with an accusative noun: that is, an argument aimed at something.

Amusingly, the most common word for "proof" is also *argumentum*, in the sense of proving something in court, or finishing a mathematical theorem. Instead, I'd use *indicium*, which means evidence you can present before a court.

For "work", since this is specifically work designed to be difficult without actually accomplishing anything useful, I'd say *labor*: literally "toil" or "drudgery".

All together, that would be ***argumentum ad indicium laboris***.

However, this sounds somewhat unwieldy, and is kind of an obvious calque: it's a literal translation from English, not an idiomatic one. For an idiomatic translation, I would use *onus*. Literally it means "burden", but in the sense of "something you have to suffer through" or "a duty that has to be done" (as in "burden of proof", a literal translation of Latin *onus probandi*). So an ***argumentum ad onus*** is proving your point by demonstrating what you've been through, which in this case is the one-way computation.

Answer (score 1):

A worker is having to prove that he has done his job?

How about: opera perfecto veritas prima facie facile constituit.

"With the work having been completed the truth was easily established on first sight." Showing the finished job, presumably, killed the argument.